# CSS оформление чекбокса (checkbox)

Tags: html, css, checkbox

как сделать такой чекбокс ? Меня интересует цвет.

Ссылка на пример : https://skr.sh/vGetZlFiAHw

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Так как input стилизовать нельзя, мы будем его скрывать и стилизовать span.

```
<label class="container"
  >One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Two
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Three
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Four
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

html разметка

```
.container {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 22px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}


.container input {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
}

.checkmark {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
.container input:checked~.checkmark {
 background-color: orange;
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
.checkmark:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
 display: block;
}
.container .checkmark:after {
 left: 9px;
 top: 5px;
 width: 5px;
 height: 10px;
 border: solid white;
 border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Ну и css.